# How to Save Object in SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter

first I got json from socket now further I got an array object from socket. How to store an object in SharedPreferences below I post the my current code how many things I need to change

**this is my old code in which I got String**

```
socket.on('message', (data) {
  print('Rates' + json.encode(data));

  setMainRate(data);
  NotifySocketUpdate.controller_maindata.add(data);
});
```

I got data from socket now like below I save the rates to SharedPreferences and my debugger not get in to this

```
setMainRate(String Responce) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('MainRate', Responce); /// Note:- I dose not get any key from soket 
}
```

so how I can do this any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```dart
socket.on('message', (data) {
  setMainRate(json.encode(data));
  NotifySocketUpdate.controller_maindata.add(data);
});
```

Comment: already try that